# VBA retain info after database synchronisation

Tags: sql, excel, vba

So, in a Workbook, I have two worksheets: One has a table full of ideas which is linked to an `SQL` database, and the other will have certain ideas selected from that table.

From the database table, I want to copy ideas that meet specific criteria to a second table. There they will be given certain numerical rankings by the user

```
Idea 1    0    4    5    3    8
Idea 2    7    5    1    5    4
Idea 3    1    2    8    8    2
```

Upon the clock of an included button, i want to update the database table, and copy over any *NEW* ideas into the ratings table, so that it may resemble the following.

```
Idea 1    0    4    5    3    8
Idea 2    7    5    1    5    4
Idea 3    1    2    8    8    2
New Idea1  
New Idea2
```

How can I accomplish this copying? I can't imagine a way to do this without overwriting the already included ratings.

## Code

Code used to copy all ID numbers to rating table.

```
Sub CopyFilter()

Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set rng2 = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1) _
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

If rng2 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No data to copy"
Else
    Set rng = Worksheets("Ideas").ListObjects("IdeasTable"). _
        ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Copy
    
    Worksheets("WFNs").Range("B5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, _
    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    
End If
   
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Worksheets("WFNs").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why do you think the old ideas would be overwritten?

Comment: I'm pretty new to VBA, and the only method i can imagine is to sort the source table, leaving only the desired entries, then copy those over to the sorting table. IF there were ideas already present, they would be overwritten, as i cannot guarantee that they are in the same order, or that the new ideas will be at the end of the list.

Comment: Have you tried some code that you could post? You can either select only new items from the table or save the old items in a variable and compare the old items with the new items.

Comment: How would i go about copying only the new rows?

Comment: Your description is to general. Provide some of your code so we have a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is, save the information about what you inserted.
First, declare a global variable like this:

```
Dim startRow as Long
```

In your sub:

```
If startRow = 0 Then
    startRow = 1 
End If 

With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set rng2 = .Offset(startRow, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1) _
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

Instead of always copying the whole range, you only copy the new entries.
Now that you have the starting row, you can use that in your if to paste your data AFTER the old date:

```
Else
    Set rng = Worksheets("Ideas").ListObjects("IdeasTable"). _
        ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    rng.Offset(startRow, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Copy

    Worksheets("WFNs").Range("B" & (startRow + 4)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, _
    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    startRow = rng.Rows.Count - 1
End If
```

I only changed rows with startRow in it. (Not tested ;))

Comment: If you have more questions, just ask :)